# Simple if else statement is not working in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

*Update*:

I want to insert data conditionally

Why this MariaDB query has errors:

```
if 2 > 1 then
 select 'hi'
else
 select 'bye'
end if
```

This is the error:

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'else select 'bye' end if' at line 3

```
if (exists (select * from teachers where name = 'Jennifer'))
    then
        -- do nothing
    else
        insert into teachers (name, age)
        values ('Jennifer', 30)
    end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `IF` can be used like this outside of a stored procedure or function.  You may use the `IF()` function or a `CASE` expression instead:

```
SELECT IF(2 > 1, 'hi', 'bye')
```

OR

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 2 > 1 THEN 'hi' ELSE 'bye' END
```